# How to use git clone to set up the repo without downloading files?

Tags: git, git-clone, git-filter

To manage yarn workspaces I am copying the pertinent subfolders into temporary folders and push them into their respective git repositories

To setup these repositories I am using `git clone`, which downloads everything and sets up the origin and remote configuration (and then copy files)

Can I skip the downloading of the repo folders?

Would this work?

```
git clone --filter=blob:none --no-checkout <repo>
```

---

**EDIT**

The usual way would be (as said by @edd34 and @pallgeuer below) with `git init` and `remote add origin`, but with the `git clone` above is only one line

-> what are the differences? What is achieved with this approach? And if incorrect, is there any way to get the same (provided a remote already exists) with `git clone`?

Comment: Would `git init` followed by `git remote add origin REMOTE` do what you want? Or is that then missing something still that you want? Maybe you can clarify what exact behaviour you are trying to achieve with an example.

Comment: As with the response below, yes I know that this would be the typical way, I'm wondering what's the difference between doing it like you say and doing it through a `git clone ...` as above

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The command:

```
$ git clone --no-checkout <repo> $(pwd)
```

will correctly clone only the `.git` folder, and no files, in the current working directory.

This should be equivalent to the more standard workflow:

```
$ git init
$ git remote add origin <url>
$ git fetch origin
```

You end up with the `.git` folder in your working directory and don't perform the HEAD checkout.

Answer (score 0):

here how you can do it :

1. Create a git repository inside an empty repository :

`git init`

2. Add your remote repository :

`git remote add origin <url_repo>`

3. Perform a fetch to update your local repository :

`git fetch`

4. You can also checkout a specific folder/file :

`git checkout -- <relative_path_to_folder_or_file_to_checkout>`

Comment: Yes, but what is the difference between yours and mine?